# Insert a multidimensional array into a multidimensional array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, insert, putimagedata

I have 2 multidimensional arrays. I want to insert the small array values into the larger array at a specific location.

```
var largeArray = [...Array(4)].map(e => Array(4).fill(0));
var smallArray = [...Array(2)].map(e => Array(2).fill(1));
```

[image: Example]

This is very similar to canvas context **putImageData()** function, where you can insert a block of values anywhere on the canvas. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData

However, I am not using a canvas and I want to "PutSmallArray" into the large array a specific X,Y location.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplistic way to achieve what you want is just to iterate over the `smallArray` values and indexes, using them to insert those values at the appropriate offset into `largeArray`:

```js
var largeArray = [...Array(4)].map(e => Array(4).fill(0));
var smallArray = [...Array(2)].map(e => Array(2).fill(1));

function insertArray(big, small, x, y) {
  small.forEach((a, i) => a.forEach((v, j) => big[y + i][x + j] = v));
  return big;
}

console.log(insertArray(largeArray, smallArray, 1, 1));
```

Note that this code doesn't check whether `smallArray` fits inside `largeArray` at the `x,y` coordinates specified. If that might not be the case, then dependent on the result you desire (an unmodified array or only the elements that fit modified), you will need to check whether the indexes fall outside the bounds of `largeArray` e.g.

```js
var largeArray = [...Array(4)].map(e => Array(4).fill(0));
var smallArray = [...Array(2)].map(e => Array(2).fill(1));

// don't update unless the array fits perfectly
function insertArray(big, small, x, y) {
  if (small.length + y > largeArray.length ||
      small[0].length + x > largeArray[0].length)
      return big;
  small.forEach((a, i) => a.forEach((v, j) => big[y + i][x + j] = v));
  return big;
}

console.log(insertArray(largeArray, smallArray, 3, 1));
```

Comment: I cannot wrap my head around what the main line is doing. "small.forEach((a, i) => a.forEach((v, j) => big[y + i][x + j] = v));" I can't find any resources to explain the syntax to do a ForEach loop on multidimensional arrays. What does A and I correspond to? forEach((a, i). What does V & J correspond to? I can't follow the code to understand what big[y + i][x + j] is pointing to.

Comment: Is it possible to use For loops instead of the ForEach statement? Currently the code causes an "undefined" error and I cannot determine where or why.

Comment: for (var a=0; a < small.length; a++){
    var xRow = small[a];
    for (var b=0; b < xRow.length; b++){
        big[offsetX + a][offsetY + b] = small[a][b];
    }
}

This?

Comment: @Selzier that looks about right except that the first index is actually `y` (it is the row) and the second `x` (the column), so you should swap the offset values.

Comment: Got it working, thanks! https://i.postimg.cc/MHt3Rc60/terrainmesh.jpg

Comment: I am pulling terrain height data from World of Warcraft and moving the data into Unity game engine where a "Unity Terrain" is generated from the data. In WoW, the height data is saved in 16x16 subchunks and 256 of those represent a complete "chunk" of terrain. The code now inserts 256 subchunks into their correct location and the image above shows a 1:1 copy of WoW Terrain translated into Unity Terrain. Now I can make my own adventure game which occurs in Azeroth, or even render a 3d music video in Azshara's Crater: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E19QJ7-sCVc